# Can a ViewController contain multiple Parent (ie containing) Controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The title sets the question quite clear.. but here is a bit of context to potentially make things clearer:

I'm working on an email client [app](https://github.com/abbood/remailPOP3) that attaches a UINavigationController as a root VC to the main window (you can see the UI hirarchy [here](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) under *how the UI works*):

```
    HomeViewController *homeController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```

later on it pushes view controllers to the navigation controller ie folder view->mailbox view->mail view etc:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someController animated:YES];
```

I would like to implement the [sliding view controller effect](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) on the mail view.

The problem is that the sliding view controller effect is implemented as a [Custom Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). The assumption is that you initaite the app by starting the containing view controller (let's call it `ECSlidingViewController`) which is the window root view controller.. then you add to it the top view controller (ie the first view controller that is displayed):

```
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTop"];
```

and then you attach view controllers that are supposed to appear under the top view controller (`slidingViewController` is and always is the only containing controller in this example):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
  }

  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
  [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
}
```

what i'm trying to figure out is.. given that my mail view is technically a child view controller to the `UINavigationController`, can it also be a child to this so-called `ECSlidingViewController`? b/c I want it to be included amongst the navigation controllers parented/controlled by the nav controller, and i want it to slide up and down.. which entails that it must be *also* a child of the `ECSlidingViewController`.

Further, supposing that a VC can have more than one parent.. in the context of the above example.. where should I add that parent in the view hierarchy? should I add it as a child of the UINavigationController? would that be a consistent with best practices (assuming there are some)?

Comment: upon further investigation.. it makes no sense to make the mailview controller (which in itself contains a scrollView subview) to be the child of `ECSlidingViewController`.. as it already receives panning gestures.. it only makes sense for the UINavbar to be a child of `ECSlidingViewController`.. but then it would be necessary to restrict the effect of `ECSlidingViewController` to when the mailview is displayed only.. still investigating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**short answer**

no.. a viewcontroller cannot contain multiple parent controllers.. this is mentioned almost explicitly in the description of UIView Class Reference [insertSubview:aboveSubview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview%3aaboveSubview%3a):
`Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.` 
Since every view controller is directly associated with one view, it follows from the above that a view controller cannot have multiple parent controllers.

**long answer**

After much research and playing with the code.. it turns out that i was looking at the problem wrong.. to make a long story short.. a custom container view controller follows the same rules that apply to pre-built container controllers like UINavigation and UITab.. and at any point a custom container can be included as a child of another controller and vice versa.. this point is best summarized [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW17):

`A container controller can be both a parent to other controllers and a child of another container. Ultimately, this combination of controllers establishes a view controller hierarchy.`

hence, if you are wondering if you should attach two parents to the same view controller.. then you should probably re-think your view hierarchy architecture.. b/c this scenario shouldn't happen. in the context of the question above.. i should just make the UINavigationController a child of my custom containing controller.. and since I have [flexibility of communication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) between children and parents and between siblings.. i can make the UINavigation slide up and down only when the Mailview is selected.